# HWND variable defined in global scope breaks compilation

Tags: c++, winapi

For some reason when I declare my control in global scope my appication will not compile. When I declare the variable inline everything is fine. The following will not compile:

```
 //Global
    HWND hEdit;

    ...

    case WM_CREATE:
            {
                // Create an edit box
                 hEdit= CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                    "EDIT",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                    ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                    50,
                    100,
                    200,
                    100,
                    hwnd,
                    (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                    NULL);
                HGDIOBJ hfDefault = GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);

...

}
break;
```

The following will not compile. The error is:

> 'HGDIOBJ' : illegal use of this type as an expression

However if I define `hEdit` inline within my switch this error goes away.

So this will compile:

```
 case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Create an edit box
            HWND hEdit= CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50,
                100,
                200,
                100,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);
            HGDIOBJ hfDefault = GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
...

} break;
```

I must be overlooking something simple but I cannot find it. Can someone tell me what I'm overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any issues. What happens if you have both a global `hEdit` *and* a local `hEdit` (so that the local variable hides the global one?). Do you still get a compilation error?

Comment: No. The error goes away. But I need to be able to get reference to this control else where in the code. So i need it defined in global scope.

Comment: In the non-compiling version, what are the last few lines before the declaration of `hEdit`?

Comment: @Nick: I'm not suggesting that as a fix; just trying to troubleshoot. Sounds like something's going on here we can't see from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argg... I named this file with a .c rather than a .cpp

Not sure why they would result in the problem I was seeing but I noticed I was getting an 'undeclared identifier' error as well. Renaming the file did the trick. I think I'll call it a night :)

Thanks for the comments and replies.

Comment: Because a 'C' file is treated as C not C++ (at least be default). And in C all variable declarations must be the first statement(s) in a block.

Comment: (In C89, that is. The rule is lifted in C99, but we're talking about MSVC here).

Answer (score 0):

Is your global variable by any chance declared before the #include?

Comment: No. :) But I wouldn't past me.